# Processing and updating a large file row by row

Tags: c#, file, file-io, batch-processing

So I am processing a 200 mb txt file and I have to read each row in the file update one or two columns and then save the same. What is the best way to achieve the same?

I was thinking of lading into a datatable but holding that big of a file in memory is a big pain.

I realise I should do it in batches but what is the best way to achieve the same?

I dont think I want to load into a dB first cos I cant do a mass update anyways. i Have to do a line by line read there too.

Just as an update my files basically have columns in any order and I need to update two or more columns all the time.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have to have access to more than one line of text at a time? ie. are you creating sums or something that needs access across rows? Or do you just need one line of text, process, write it out, move on to next?

Comment: edited the doc explaining what update i need to perform

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read a line, parse it, and write fields into a temp file. When all the lines are done, delete the original file and rename the temp file.

Comment: I like this idea. example pleasE?

Answer (score 1):

To add to what Ants said...

You have options ...

- Line by line:

  > ```
  > StreamReader fileStream = new StreamReader( sourceFileName );
  > StreamWriter ansiWriter = new StreamWriter( destinationFileName,  
  >   false, Encoding.GetEncoding( 20127 ) );  
  > string fileContent;  
  > while ( ( fileContent = fileStream.ReadLine() ) != null )  
  > {  
  >     YourReplaceMethod( fileContent );  
  >     ansiWriter.WriteLine( fileContent );  
  > }
  > fileStream.Close();  
  > ansiWriter.Close();
  > ```
- Bulk (today's boxes should be able to handle 200MB w/o problems):

  > ```
  > byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes( sourceFileName );
  > byte[] writeMeBytes = YourReplaceMethod( bytes );
  > File.WriteAllBytes( destinationFileName, writeMeBytes );
  > ```